# Count number of rows per group and add result to original data frame

Tags: r, count, aggregate, r-faq

Say I have a `data.frame` object:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                 type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','plate'),
                 num=c(4,5,12,4,3))
```

Now I want to count the number of rows (observations) of for each combination of `name` and `type`. This can be done like so:

```
table(df[ , c("name","type")])
```

or possibly also with `plyr`, (though I am not sure how).

However, how do I get the results incorporated into the original data frame?  So that the results will look like this:

```
df
#    name  type num count
# 1 black chair   4     2
# 2 black chair   5     2
# 3 black  sofa  12     1
# 4   red  sofa   4     1
# 5   red plate   3     1
```

where `count` now stores the results from the aggregation.

A solution with `plyr` could be interesting to learn as well, though I would like to see how this is done with base R.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Using `data.table`:**

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)

# or coerce to data.table by reference:
# setDT(df)

dt[ , count := .N, by = .(name, type)]
```

For pre-`data.table 1.8.2` alternative, see edit history.

---

**Using `dplyr`:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name, type) %>%
  mutate(count = n())
```

Or simply:

```
add_count(df, name, type)
```

---

**Using `plyr`:**

```
plyr::ddply(df, .(name, type), transform, count = length(num))
```

Comment: Do you need "setkeyv(dt, c('name', 'type'))"?

Answer (score 31):

You can use `ave`:

```
df$count <- ave(df$num, df[,c("name","type")], FUN=length)
```

Comment: Could also do it a bit cleaner perhaps using `transform(df, count = ave(num, name, type, FUN = length))` or `with`

Comment: If you have **lots of data**, this command is SUPERSLOW

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
> ddply(df,.(name,type),transform,count = NROW(piece))
   name  type num count
1 black chair   4     2
2 black chair   5     2
3 black  sofa  12     1
4   red plate   3     1
5   red  sofa   4     1
```

or perhaps more intuitively,

```
> ddply(df,.(name,type),transform,count = length(num))
   name  type num count
1 black chair   4     2
2 black chair   5     2
3 black  sofa  12     1
4   red plate   3     1
5   red  sofa   4     1
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do your work :

```
df_agg <- aggregate(num~name+type,df,FUN=NROW)
names(df_agg)[3] <- "count"
df <- merge(df,df_agg,by=c('name','type'),all.x=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The base `R` function `aggregate` will obtain the counts with a one-liner, but adding those counts back to the original `data.frame` seems to take a bit of processing.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                 type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','plate'),
                 num=c(4,5,12,4,3))
df
#    name  type num
# 1 black chair   4
# 2 black chair   5
# 3 black  sofa  12
# 4   red  sofa   4
# 5   red plate   3

rows.per.group  <- aggregate(rep(1, length(paste0(df$name, df$type))),
                             by=list(df$name, df$type), sum)
rows.per.group
#   Group.1 Group.2 x
# 1   black   chair 2
# 2     red   plate 1
# 3   black    sofa 1
# 4     red    sofa 1

my.summary <- do.call(data.frame, rows.per.group)
colnames(my.summary) <- c(colnames(df)[1:2], 'rows.per.group')
my.data <- merge(df, my.summary, by = c(colnames(df)[1:2]))
my.data
#    name  type num rows.per.group
# 1 black chair   4              2
# 2 black chair   5              2
# 3 black  sofa  12              1
# 4   red plate   3              1
# 5   red  sofa   4              1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *sqldf* package:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, b.cnt
       from df a,
           (select name, type, count(1) as cnt
            from df
            group by name, type) b
      where a.name = b.name and
            a.type = b.type")

#    name  type num cnt
# 1 black chair   4   2
# 2 black chair   5   2
# 3 black  sofa  12   1
# 4   red  sofa   4   1
# 5   red plate   3   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using [add_tally](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/tally) from `dplyr`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                 type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','plate'),
                 num=c(4,5,12,4,3))
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name, type) %>%
  add_tally(name = "count")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Groups:   name, type [4]
#>   name  type    num count
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 black chair     4     2
#> 2 black chair     5     2
#> 3 black sofa     12     1
#> 4 red   sofa      4     1
#> 5 red   plate     3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A two line alternative is to generate a variable of 0s and then fill it in with `split<-`, `split`, and `lengths` like this:

```
# generate vector of 0s
df$count <-0L

# fill it in
split(df$count, df[c("name", "type")]) <- lengths(split(df$num, df[c("name", "type")]))
```

This returns the desired result

```
df
   name  type num count
1 black chair   4     2
2 black chair   5     2
3 black  sofa  12     1
4   red  sofa   4     1
5   red plate   3     1
```

Essentially, the RHS calculates the lengths of each name-type combination, returning a named vector of length 6 with 0s for "red.chair" and  "black.plate." This is fed to the LHS with `split <-` which takes the vector and appropriately adds the values in their given spots. This is essentially what `ave` does, as you can see that the second to final line of `ave` is

```
split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
```

However, `lengths` is an optimized version of `sapply(list, length)`.

Answer (score 1):

You were just one step away from incorporating the row count into the base dataset.

Using the `tidy()` function from the `broom` package, convert the frequency table into a data frame and inner join with `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                         type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','plate'),
                         num=c(4,5,12,4,3))
library(broom)
df <- merge(df, tidy(table(df[ , c("name","type")])), by=c("name","type"))
df
   name  type num Freq
1 black chair   4    2
2 black chair   5    2
3 black  sofa  12    1
4   red plate   3    1
5   red  sofa   4    1
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple line in base R:

```
df$count = table(interaction(df[, (c("name", "type"))]))[interaction(df[, (c("name", "type"))])]
```

Same in two lines, for clarity/efficiency:

```
fact = interaction(df[, (c("name", "type"))])
df$count = table(fact)[fact]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `collapse`, with `fcount`. [`fcount` is noticeably faster than any other options.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76714249/13460602)

```r
library(collapse)
df |> 
  fcount(name, type, add = TRUE, name = "count")

#    name  type num count
# 1 black chair   4     2
# 2 black chair   5     2
# 3 black  sofa  12     1
# 4   red  sofa   4     1
# 5   red plate   3     1
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way that generalizes more:

```
df$count <- unsplit(lapply(split(df, df[c("name","type")]), nrow), df[c("name","type")])
```

Comment: Please explain how does this generalize more?