# Count number of rows within each group

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, r-faq

I have a dataframe and I would like to count the number of rows within each group. I reguarly use the `aggregate` function to sum data as follows:

```
df2 <- aggregate(x ~ Year + Month, data = df1, sum)
```

Now, I would like to count observations but can't seem to find the proper argument for `FUN`. Intuitively, I thought it would be as follows:

```
df2 <- aggregate(x ~ Year + Month, data = df1, count)
```

But, no such luck.

Any ideas?

---

Some toy data:

```
set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:20,
                  Year = sample(2012:2014, 20, replace = TRUE),
                  Month = sample(month.abb[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: `nrow`, `NROW`, `length`...

Comment: I keep reading this question as asking for a fun way to count things (as opposed to the many unfun ways, I guess).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: `nrow` did not work for me but `NROW` and `length`worked fine. +1

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The tidyverse/dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% count(Year, Month)
```

Comment: Is there a way to aggregate a variable and do counting too (like 2 functions in aggregation: mean + count)? I need to get the mean of a column and the number of rows for the same value in other column

Comment: I'd `cbind` the results of `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, mean)` and `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, length)`

Comment: I have done it, but it seems that I get 2 times each column except the one that is aggregated; so I have done a merge on them and it seems to be ok

Comment: I don't know but this could be useful as well... `df %>% group_by(group, variable) %>% mutate(count = n())`

Comment: Yes dplyr is best practice now.

Comment: I'm a daily dplyr user but still wouldn't call it necessarily best practice, more like common personal preference

Comment: You are perfectly right - dplyr isn't best for all cases, e.g. data.table or poorman might be preferable. And what does 'best practice' mean anyway?

Answer (score 85):

Following @Joshua's suggestion, here's one way you might count the number of observations in your `df` dataframe where `Year` = 2007 and `Month` = Nov (assuming they are columns):

```
nrow(df[,df$YEAR == 2007 & df$Month == "Nov"])
```

and with `aggregate`, following @GregSnow:

```
aggregate(x ~ Year + Month, data = df, FUN = length)
```

Answer (score 61):

**`dplyr` package does this with `count`/`tally` commands, or the `n()` function**:

First, some data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:6, rep(c(1, 2, 3), 2)), year = 1993:2004, month = c(1, 1:11))
```

Now the count:

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, year, month)
#piping
df %>% count(year, month)
```

We can also use a slightly longer version with piping and the `n()` function:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(number = n())
```

or the `tally` function:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  tally()
```

Answer (score 44):

An old question without a `data.table` solution. So here goes...

Using `.N`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, .N, by = list(year, month)]
```

Comment: standard nowadays to use `.()` instead of `list()` and `setDT()` to convert a data.frame to data.table. So in one step `setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(year, month)]`.

Comment: Seeing this I'm wondering if it solves what was once a deal-breaker for my use of data.table. Trying `table` within data.table was excruciatingly slow, which was a huge puzzle for me. I've left that rather large dataset behind me after retirement, so will not be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 25):

The simple option to use with `aggregate` is the `length` function which will give you the length of the vector in the subset.  Sometimes a little more robust is to use `function(x) sum( !is.na(x) )`.

Answer (score 22):

Create a new variable `Count` with a value of 1 for each row:

```
df1["Count"] <-1
```

Then aggregate dataframe, summing by the `Count` column:

```
df2 <- aggregate(df1[c("Count")], by=list(Year=df1$Year, Month=df1$Month), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Just to note that if you are using the default, non-formula method for `aggregate`, there is no need to rename each variable in `by=` like `list(year=df1$year)` etc. A `data.frame` is a `list` already so `aggregate(df1[c("Count")], by=df1[c("Year", "Month")], FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)` will work.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative to the `aggregate()` function in this case would be `table()` with `as.data.frame()`, which would also indicate which combinations of Year and Month are associated with zero occurrences

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(1:6,rep(c(1,2,3),2)),year=1993:2004,month=c(1,1:11))

myAns<-as.data.frame(table(df[,c("year","month")]))
```

And without the zero-occurring combinations

```
myAns[which(myAns$Freq>0),]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to include 0 counts for month-years that are missing in the data, you can use a little `table` magic.

```
data.frame(with(df1, table(Year, Month)))
```

---

For example, the toy data.frame in the question, df1, contains no observations of January 2014.

```
df1
    x Year Month
1   1 2012   Feb
2   2 2014   Feb
3   3 2013   Mar
4   4 2012   Jan
5   5 2014   Feb
6   6 2014   Feb
7   7 2012   Jan
8   8 2014   Feb
9   9 2013   Mar
10 10 2013   Jan
11 11 2013   Jan
12 12 2012   Jan
13 13 2014   Mar
14 14 2012   Mar
15 15 2013   Feb
16 16 2014   Feb
17 17 2014   Mar
18 18 2012   Jan
19 19 2013   Mar
20 20 2012   Jan
```

The base R `aggregate` function does not return an observation for January 2014.

```
aggregate(x ~ Year + Month, data = df1, FUN = length)
  Year Month x
1 2012   Feb 1
2 2013   Feb 1
3 2014   Feb 5
4 2012   Jan 5
5 2013   Jan 2
6 2012   Mar 1
7 2013   Mar 3
8 2014   Mar 2
```

If you would like an observation of this month-year with 0 as the count, then the above code will return a data.frame with counts for all month-year combinations:

```
data.frame(with(df1, table(Year, Month)))
  Year Month Freq
1 2012   Feb    1
2 2013   Feb    1
3 2014   Feb    5
4 2012   Jan    5
5 2013   Jan    2
6 2014   Jan    0
7 2012   Mar    1
8 2013   Mar    3
9 2014   Mar    2
```

Answer (score 5):

A [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) solution using `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Year, Month, COUNT(*) as Freq
       FROM df1
       GROUP BY Year, Month")
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `collapse` package in `R`

```
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
    fgroup_by(year, month) %>%
    fsummarise(number = fNobs(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

For my aggregations I usually end up wanting to see mean and "how big is this group" (a.k.a. length).
So this is my handy snippet for those occasions;

```
agg.mean <- aggregate(columnToMean ~ columnToAggregateOn1*columnToAggregateOn2, yourDataFrame, FUN="mean")
agg.count <- aggregate(columnToMean ~ columnToAggregateOn1*columnToAggregateOn2, yourDataFrame, FUN="length")
aggcount <- agg.count$columnToMean
agg <- cbind(aggcount, agg.mean)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(count= n())
```

Answer (score 2):

Two very fast `collapse` options are `GRPN` and `fcount`. `fcount` is a fast version of `dplyr::count` and uses the same syntax. You can use `add = TRUE` to add it a as a column (`mutate`-like):

```r
library(collapse)
fcount(df1, Year, Month) #or df1 %>% fcount(Year, Month)

#   Year Month N
# 1 2012   Feb 4
# 2 2014   Jan 3
# 3 2013   Mar 2
# 4 2013   Feb 2
# 5 2012   Jan 2
# 6 2012   Mar 2
# 7 2013   Jan 1
# 8 2014   Feb 3
# 9 2014   Mar 1
```

`GRPN` is closer to `collapse`'s original syntax. First, group the data with `GRP`. Then use `GRPN`. By default, `GRPN` creates an expanded vector that match the original data. (In `dplyr`, it would be equivalent to using `mutate`). Use `expand = FALSE` to output the summarized vector.

```r
library(collapse)
GRPN(GRP(df1, .c(Year, Month)), expand = FALSE)
```

---

Microbenchmark with a 100,000 x 3 data frame and 4997 different groups.
`collapse::fcount` is much faster than any other option.

```r
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = gl(1000, 100),
           y = rbinom(100000, 4, .5),
           z = runif(100000))
dt <- df

mb <- 
  microbenchmark(
  aggregate = aggregate(z ~ x + y, data = df, FUN = length),
  count = count(df, x, y),
  data.table = setDT(dt)[, .N, by = .(x, y)],
  'collapse::fnobs' = df %>% fgroup_by(x, y) %>% fsummarise(number = fnobs(z)),
  'collapse::GRPN' = GRPN(GRP(df, .c(x, y)), expand = FALSE),
  'collapse::fcount' = fcount(df, x, y)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#        aggregate 159.5459 203.87385 227.787186 223.93050 246.36025 335.0302   100
#            count  55.1765  63.83560  74.715889  73.60195  79.20170 196.8888   100
#       data.table   8.4483  15.57120  18.308277  18.10790  20.65460  31.2666   100
#  collapse::fnobs   3.3325   4.16145   5.695979   5.18225   6.27720  22.7697   100
#   collapse::GRPN   3.0254   3.80890   4.844727   4.59445   5.50995  13.6649   100
# collapse::fcount   1.2222   1.57395   3.087526   1.89540   2.47955  22.5756   100
```

Comment: That's pretty impressive. I wonder why I haven't seen more answers that use the collapse package?

Comment: Yes, `collapse` is impressive for its speed, and has pretty much all the useful function one could need for data manipulation. It's relatively new and can be, like any other grammar, a bit difficult to grasp in the first place, hence a timid audience so far, but I'm trying to populate SO with more `collapse` solutions, especially in the most-viewed questions like this one. SebKrantz, the author of the package, is also active on SO.

Comment: I was so impressed with collapse that I wrote a package 'timeplyr' (on CRAN) to combine collapse with dplyr syntax. In particular see `timeplyr::fcount()`

Answer (score 1):

Considering @Ben answer, R would throw an error if `df1` does not contain `x` column. But it can be solved elegantly with `paste`:

```
aggregate(paste(Year, Month) ~ Year + Month, data = df1, FUN = NROW)
```

Similarly, it can be generalized if more than two variables are used in grouping:

```
aggregate(paste(Year, Month, Day) ~ Year + Month + Day, data = df1, FUN = NROW)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use *table* function

```r
df <- data.frame(a=rep(1:8,rep(c(1,2,3, 4),2)),year=2011:2021,month=c(1,3:10))

new_data <- as.data.frame(table(df[,c("year","month")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by` functions as `by(df1$Year, df1$Month, count)` that will produce a list of needed aggregation.

The output will look like,

```
df1$Month: Feb
     x freq
1 2012    1
2 2013    1
3 2014    5
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
df1$Month: Jan
     x freq
1 2012    5
2 2013    2
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
df1$Month: Mar
     x freq
1 2012    1
2 2013    3
3 2014    2
>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of wonderful answers here already, but I wanted to throw in 1 more option for those wanting to add a new column to the original dataset that contains the number of times that row is repeated.

```
df1$counts <- sapply(X = paste(df1$Year, df1$Month), 
                     FUN = function(x) { sum(paste(df1$Year, df1$Month) == x) })
```

The same could be accomplished by combining any of the above answers with the `merge()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying the aggregate solutions above and you get the error:

invalid type (list) for variable

Because you're using date or datetime stamps, try using as.character on the variables:

```
aggregate(x ~ as.character(Year) + Month, data = df, FUN = length)
```

On one or both of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fcount` from my package timeplyr that accepts dplyr syntax but uses collapse under the hood.

```r
library(collapse)
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = gl(1000, 100),
                 y = rbinom(100000, 4, .5),
                 z = runif(100000))
dt <- df

mb <- 
  microbenchmark(
    aggregate = aggregate(z ~ x + y, data = df, FUN = length),
    count = count(df, x, y),
    data.table = setDT(dt)[, .N, by = .(x, y)],
    'collapse::fcount' = collapse::fcount(df, x, y),
    'timeplyr::fcount1' = timeplyr::fcount(df, x, y),
    'timeplyr::fcount2' = timeplyr::fcount(df, .cols = c("x", "y"), order = FALSE)
  )

mb
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>               expr     min        lq       mean    median        uq      max
#>          aggregate 84.0802 105.10615 123.593910 115.97675 134.65225 255.7676
#>              count 40.8108  50.82485  60.718189  56.81630  68.85530  97.4791
#>         data.table  3.7106   5.07485   6.273698   5.66645   6.44855  20.0465
#>   collapse::fcount  1.0118   1.37400   1.915809   1.61105   2.08465  13.9825
#>  timeplyr::fcount1  3.0390   3.74840   5.361852   4.56755   5.83405  44.0072
#>  timeplyr::fcount2  1.3787   1.98625   2.640338   2.47025   3.03450   8.6333
#>  neval
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>