# R count occurrences of an element by groups

Tags: r, counter

What is the easiest way to count the occurrences of a an element on a vector or data.frame at every grouop?
I don't mean just counting the total (as other stackoverflow questions ask) but giving a different number to every succesive occurence.

for example for this simple dataframe: (but I will work with dataframes with more columns)

```
mydata <- data.frame(A=c("A","A","A","B","B","A", "A"))
```

I've found this solution:

```
cbind(mydata,myorder=ave(rep(1,nrow(mydata)),mydata$A, FUN=cumsum))
```

and here the result:

```
 A myorder  
 A       1  
 A       2  
 A       3  
 B       1  
 B       2  
 A       4  
 A       5
```

Isn't there any single command to do it?. Or using an specialized package?

I want it to later use tidyr's spread() function.

My question is not the same than 
[Is there an aggregate FUN option to count occurrences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/is-there-an-aggregate-fun-option-to-count-occurrences)
because I don't want to know the total number of occurrencies at the end but the cumulative occurencies till every element.

OK, my problem is a little bit more complex

```
mydata <- data.frame(group=c("x","x","x","x","y","y", "y"), letter=c("A","A","A","B","B","A", "A"))
```

I only know to solve the first example I wrote above.
But what happens when I want it also by a second grouping variable?
something like occurrencies(letter) by group.

```
group letter  "occurencies within group"  
 x      A       1  
 x      A       2  
 x      A       3  
 x      B       1  
 y      B       1  
 y      A       1  
 y      A       2
```

I've found the way with

> ave(rep(1,nrow(mydata)),list(mydata$group, mydata$letter), FUN=cumsum)
>   though it shoould be something easier.

Comment: this question has been asked many times ... please serach before

Comment: It's not the same because I don't want to know the total number of occurrencies at the end but the cumulative occurencies till every element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, myorder := 1:.N, by = .(group, letter)]
```

The `by` argument makes the table be dealt with within the groups of the column called `A`. `.N` is the number of rows within that group (if the `by` argument was empty it would be the number of rows in the table), so for each sub-table, each row is indexed from 1 to the number of rows in that sub-table.

```
mydata
   group letter myorder
1:     x      A       1
2:     x      A       2
3:     x      A       3
4:     x      B       1
5:     y      B       1
6:     y      A       1
7:     y      A       2
```

or a `dplyr` solution which is pretty much the same

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(group, letter) %>% 
  mutate(myorder = 1:n())
```

Comment: Good.  What if I also want it "by" a second grouping variable?

Comment: @skan `by = list(A, B)`. A common shortcut for writing `list` in `data.table` is dot syntax, i.e. `by = .(A, B)` where `B` is the second variable. Sorry, I don't have a `tidyr` soln.

Comment: Or `mydata[, myorder := 1:.N, by = .(group, letter)]` in the case specified after the edit.

Comment: Good, Could you add it to the main answer, please?
And if you add a tidyr , dplyr o base solution it would be even better

Comment: Anything with by() or ave() ?

Comment: I don't use `tidyr` unfortunately, so I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @skan - with `ave()` you could do `transform(mydata, count = ave(rep(1, nrow(mydata)), A, FUN = seq_along))` similar to what you show in your post.  Also, `tidyr` is not for this kind of work.  It's for data cleaning.

Comment: And on the other data `transform(mydata, count = ave(rep(1, nrow(mydata)), letter, group, FUN = seq_along))`