# Sum Multiple Text and Create New Column in R

Tags: r

How can i calculate and print the result in new column?

**Case:**

Horror
Horror
Horror
Horror
Adventure
Action
Action
Horror

**Output:**

**|Category   | Total   |**
| Horror    | 5      |
| Action   | 2   |
| Adventure   | 1 |

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/is-there-an-aggregate-fun-option-to-count-occurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
as.data.frame(table(df1$Category))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Total=.N), Category]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Category) %>%
   summmarise(Total=n())
```