# Generate Frequency Tables for Unordered Data

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

Assuming a dataframe as set out below:

```
A<-c("John","John","James","Brad")
B<-c("Deb","Deb","Henry","Suzie")
C<-c("Barry","Beth","Deb","Louise")
D<-c("Ben","Dory","John","Simon")
df<-data.frame(A,B,C,D)
df
      A     B      C     D
1  John   Deb  Barry   Ben
2  John   Deb   Beth  Dory
3 James Henry    Deb  John
4  Brad Suzie Louise Simon
```

How does one go about generating a frequency table showing the total number of times the combination of values in column A & B are found in the same row. The output for this would look like the following.

```
       A      B     n
1   Brad  Suzie     1
2  James  Henry     1
3   John    Deb     3
```

I'm aware of simple frequency tables using `dplyr` but I'm unable to get it to work in this scenario.

Comment: Did you meant `library(dplyr);count(rbind(df[1:2], intersect(df[1:2], setNames(df[4:3], names(df)[1:2]))), A, B)`  Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)

Comment: John Deb combination is 2? not 3 because you want only 2 columns right?

Comment: I want to summarise the whole table based on the info in the first two columns. So the combination of John and Deb exists on three rows.

Comment: I am assuming that first form combination of all unique names present in column A and B and then check for number of rows where this pair is present across all columns, irrespective of sequence

Comment: This is a method I've been playing around with too. But I'm struggling to work out how to count rows based on multiple criteria which may exist in different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(A = c("John","John","James","Brad"),
               B = c("Deb","Deb","Henry","Suzie"),
               C = c("Barry","Beth","Deb","Louise"),
               D = c("Ben","Dory","John","Simon"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$seq <- paste(df$A, df$B, df$C, df$D, sep = ",")

names <- unique(c(df$A,df$B))
pairs <- combn(names, 2)
finaldf <- data.frame(name1 = NULL, name2 = NULL, count = NULL)

for(i in 1:ncol(pairs)){
  name1 <- pairs[1,i]
  name2 <- pairs[2,i]
  count <- length(which( grepl(name1,df$seq) & grepl(name2,df$seq) ))

  finaldf <- rbind(finaldf, data.frame(name1 = name1, name2 = name2, count = count))

}

finaldf

> finaldf
name1 name2 count
1   John James     1
2   John  Brad     0
3   John   Deb     3
4   John Henry     1
5   John Suzie     0
6  James  Brad     0
7  James   Deb     1
8  James Henry     1
9  James Suzie     0
10  Brad   Deb     0
11  Brad Henry     0
12  Brad Suzie     1
13   Deb Henry     1
14   Deb Suzie     0
15 Henry Suzie     0
```