# How to handle with imbalanced dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have a following problem. My dataset contains information about tennis players and number of games they played each season during their active career.

```
Name Season Games
Nadal 2015 84
Novak 2017 14
Nadal 2016 88
Federer 2018 75
Nadal 2010 45
.
.
.
```

I would like to create a new dataset that includes only players that were playing for five and more years.

I suppose, I have to somehow sum up players together and then filter them. How can I do it, please?

Comment: What have you tried so far and have you looked at any questions that have already been posted? You may find this thread helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can count and filter your dataframe.
For example, I create this dummy dataframe:

```r
df = data.frame(P = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
                y = c(1,4,5,8,7,4,2,3,4,8,7,4,1))


library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(P) %>% add_count(P) %>% filter(n > 5)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   P [1]
  P         y     n
  <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 A         1     7
2 A         4     7
3 A         5     7
4 A         8     7
5 A         7     7
6 A         4     7
7 A         2     7
```

With your dataframe, you can try:

```r
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% add_count(Name) %>% filter(n >= 5)
```