# group on two variables, and then count a string value

Tags: r, tidyverse

[image: content table]

I want to count all the O-V and G in the Kwaleitsbeoordeling column.
And I want to group on the Branche and the Status.

```
df %>% 
group_by(Status) %>% 
Group
  summarize(mean_value = count(Kwaliteitsbeoordeling))
```

How do I summarise a string value? and group on 2 different columns?

**Update:**

expected result:

[image]

Data update:

```
Project ID
<dbl>
Branche
<chr>
Status
<chr>
HUB
<chr>
Rayonmanager
<chr>
Kwaliteitsbeoordeling
<chr>
Algemene_indruk
<chr>
Arbo
<chr>
aanvullende_dienstverlening
<chr>
1   Hotels  huidig  Utrecht Janssen O   V   O   V   
2   Overheid    opgezegd    Barendrecht Platter O   O   V   O   
3   Overheid    huidig  Amsterdam   Hartman V   V   G   V   
4   Onderwijs   opgezegd    Amsterdam   Verhoeven   V   O   G   N.V.T   
5   Food    huidig  Amsterdam   Hartman O   O   O   V   
6   Retail  opgezegd    Utrecht Janssen G   O   N.V.T   V   
7   Onderwijs   huidig  Eindhoven   Willems G   V   V   V   
8   Hotels  opgezegd    Barendrecht Velzeboer   G   V   V   G   
9   Food    huidig  Amsterdam   Hartman O   O   G   O   
10  Onderwijs   opgezegd    Barendrecht Platter V   G   O   N.V.T
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by `n()` and then reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Project_ID, Branche, Kwaliteitsbeoordeling) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Kwaliteitsbeoordeling, values_from = n, 
         values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for this result, But when i do this code i'll get a mean number, and I want to see like 0= 4 times v= 5 times G = 8 times or somethign like that

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede if that is the case, you don't need the `group_by` and `summarise` in the first case.  I got confused by your `mean_value`.  In the second option, it would be `summarise(mean_value = n())`

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede can you add a dput of a small example so that I can test it.  From the image, i cannot copy

Comment: How can I add some data?

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede you can do `dput(head(mtcars))` and get the output.  similarly you can do `dput(head(yourdata))` change the number of rows so that it would make a reproducible example

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede it would make it easier with dput.  anyway will try that.  Reason is that it s not clear where the column delimiter ends

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede is `Status HUB` a single word

Comment: @ITStudentEnschede i updated the solution.  May be that helps

Comment: Thank you very much