# Fast way to get number of observations per group in data.table

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Using .N with lots of groups seems to have pretty high overhead because it's calling [.data.table a bunch of times; is there a faster way I'm missing? Here are a couple hacks; sum and max don't appear to have the overhead (my data already has the obs_num variable; if it didn't, b and c would be about the same in terms of timing. I also checked if it was any faster with one unique grouping ID and it doesn't seem to be).

```
library(data.table)

n_groups_1 = 10000
n_groups_2 = 800
n_obs_group = 4
test_dt = data.table(group_id_1 = rep(1:n_groups_1, each = n_groups_2 * n_obs_group), group_id_2 = rep(rep(1:n_groups_2, times = n_groups_1), each = n_obs_group))

test_dt[, obs_num := rowid(group_id_1, group_id_2)]



test_dt[, n_obs1 := .N, .(group_id_1, group_id_2)]
test_dt[, constant1 := 1][, n_obs2 := sum(constant1), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)][, constant1 := NULL]
test_dt[, n_obs3 := max(obs_num), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)]

setkey(test_dt, group_id_1, group_id_2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a = {test_dt[, n_obs1 := .N, .(group_id_1, group_id_2)]},
                               b = {test_dt[, constant1 := 1][, n_obs2 := sum(constant1), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)][, n_obs2 := sum(constant1), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)][, constant1 := NULL]},
                               c = {test_dt[, n_obs3 := max(obs_num), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)]},
                               times = 10)
```

You can see on the benchmarks the speed cost of .N

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
    a 4601.3196 4732.6296 4906.5689 4796.0032 4883.9187 5538.925    10   c
    b 2035.0773 2071.0749 2234.5891 2264.9387 2350.0976 2463.662    10  b 
    c  889.6202  904.4387  951.5881  929.0904  983.1265 1105.053    10 a
```

If there's not a better way of doing this right now, I guess I could submit this as a feature request. Using data.table 1.14.9 on R 4.2.0, maybe this doesn't replicate in R 4.3. Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974120/fast-way-to-count-the-number-of-observations-by-group-in-r), I suppose, but clearly the .N solution isn't the fastest possible with a large number of groups.

Comment: what about `length`?

Comment: I could not reproduce this in multiple versions of R (4.3.0, 4.2.2, 4.0.3, 3.6.3, and 3.6.1) with `data.table` 1.14.8 and 1.12.6. Solution A is 2-3 times faster than C and 4-8 times faster than B (even though you pre-process `row.id` which is not really a fair comparison). You should do `max(rowid(group_id_1, group_id_2))` within your solution. Moreover, it's better to make copies of your data.table (`test_dt1 <- copy(test_dt)`) to keep the tests entirely separate. Again, I cannot reproduce the behavior you have shown here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate in R 4.3.1:

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)

n_groups_1 = 10000
n_groups_2 = 800
n_obs_group = 4
test_dt = data.table(group_id_1 = rep(1:n_groups_1, each = n_groups_2 * n_obs_group), group_id_2 = rep(rep(1:n_groups_2, times = n_groups_1), each = n_obs_group))

test_dt[, obs_num := rowid(group_id_1, group_id_2)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  .N = dt[, n_obs := .N, .(group_id_1, group_id_2)],
  sum = dt[, constant1 := 1L][, n_obs := sum(constant1), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)][, constant1 := NULL],
  max = dt[, n_obs := max(obs_num), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)],
  collapse = fcount(test_dt, c("group_id_1", "group_id_2"), name = "n_obs", add = TRUE),
  setup = dt <- copy(test_dt),
  check = "equal",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
#>        .N 2599.5504 2868.3719 2912.352 2943.2613 2971.1768 3058.762    10
#>       sum 5827.8029 6095.9133 6289.212 6114.9947 6416.9563 7593.156    10
#>       max 5768.4920 5872.3938 6098.653 5968.0909 6078.5502 7213.395    10
#>  collapse  675.3468  703.6826  789.867  763.1862  853.7979 1037.911    10

setkey(test_dt, group_id_1, group_id_2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  .N = dt[, n_obs := .N, .(group_id_1, group_id_2)],
  sum = dt[, constant1 := 1L][, n_obs := sum(constant1), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)][, constant1 := NULL],
  max = dt[, n_obs := max(obs_num), .(group_id_1, group_id_2)],
  collapse = fcount(test_dt, c("group_id_1", "group_id_2"), name = "n_obs", add = TRUE),
  rep = dt[,n_obs := {i <- diff(c(which(obs_num == 1L) - 1L, .N)); rep(i, i)}],
  setup = dt <- copy(test_dt),
  check = "equal",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>        .N 2981.6123 3133.3371 3339.9112 3400.4474 3531.3698 3559.8926    10
#>       sum 5951.7079 6203.0055 6580.6503 6518.7434 6974.8425 7315.9413    10
#>       max 6284.5152 6814.7189 6868.5781 6902.9936 7033.0992 7307.9067    10
#>  collapse  700.2412  757.9851  830.0862  817.0100  877.2115 1062.5059    10
#>       rep  287.8740  291.4706  343.7207  310.6956  368.8832  532.0701    10
```

Comment: This is what I get

Comment: I am a big fan of {collapse} as well :-). Thanks for the bench

Comment: I get the following benchmarks running your code exactly, strange! But thanks so much for the speedup, clever!

.N: 3808.8875,       sum: 1021.1219,       max: 1298.9184,  collapse:  971.6672,       rep:  403.7601

Comment: Oh, maybe it could be data.table's parallelization kicking in?

Comment: `setDTthreads(1L)` doesn't seem to affect the relative timing. I can't think of a good explanation for your timings.

Comment: Would be interesting to add data.table:::forder retGtp=T to see how it is without any overhead

Comment: @jangorecki, Sorry, I'm not following. Add `forder` to the timings? Where's the overhead?

Comment: Overhead is in `[.data.table` method. Considering units are milliseconds, it can be very different rank. And then setDTthreads can as well has bigger impact.