# How can I count the number of rows within each group using SQL?

Tags: sql, count, grouping

Much like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941703/636987), how can I achieve the same thing in SQL?

I want to group the data first by site, then by date and then have a count that shows number of bookings on that date.

The result would be something like this:

```
Site1   2021-03-04      9
Site1   2021-03-05      5
Site1   2021-03-06      4
Site2   1900-01-01      1
Site2   2020-12-30      1
Site2   2021-01-04    325
Site2   2021-01-05    520
```

Comment: Seems, you need SELECT T.SITE,T.DATE,COUNT(*)CNTT FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T GROUP BY T.SITE,T.DATE

Comment: @Sergey This is it. Delete your comment then post it as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: This is the beautiful thing about SQL; you say you want to group your data by site and date and this translates to `GROUP BY site, date`. You say you want to have a count and this becomes `SELECT COUNT(*)`. SQL statements for simple queries are often close to how we describe the task in English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.SITE,T.DATE,COUNT(*)CNTT FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T GROUP BY T.SITE,T.DATE
```

Based on your description you need something like this query