# In grouped data, how to generate a new column that accounts for group size each row belongs to, using R package {collapse}?

Tags: r, group-by

In a grouped data frame, I want to generate a new column for the size (number of observations) of each group.

Whereas this is easy enough with `dplyr` functions, I struggle to find how to do it using tools from `collapse` package.

Let's take the `mpg` dataset from `ggplot2`. Once we group the data by `manufacturer`, we then want to compute an additional column that accounts for whether each row belongs to a group with of size > 10. With `dplyr` it's as easy as `mutate(more_than_10_obs = n() > 10)`.

```r
library(ggplot2) ## for the `mpg` dataset
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)   

mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  mutate(more_than_10_obs = n() > 10)
#> # A tibble: 234 x 2
#> # Groups:   manufacturer [15]
#>    manufacturer more_than_10_obs
#>    <chr>        <lgl>           
#>  1 audi         TRUE            
#>  2 audi         TRUE            
#>  3 audi         TRUE            
#>  4 audi         TRUE            
#>  5 audi         TRUE            
#>  6 audi         TRUE            
#>  7 audi         TRUE            
#>  8 audi         TRUE            
#>  9 audi         TRUE            
#> 10 audi         TRUE            
#> # ... with 224 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

But I have very large data and I want to speed up processing time, therefore use tools from `collapse` package. So following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66661189/6105259), I've tried to first generate a new column that simply gives the number of observations in the group that each row belongs to.

```r
library(collapse)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr) ## for pipe operator

mpg %>%
  fselect(manufacturer) %>%
  fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>%
  ftransform(idx = seq_row(.)) %>%
  ftransform(n_in_group = fNobs(idx))
#> # A tibble: 234 x 3
#>    manufacturer   idx n_in_group
#>  * <chr>        <int>      <int>
#>  1 audi             1        234
#>  2 audi             2        234
#>  3 audi             3        234
#>  4 audi             4        234
#>  5 audi             5        234
#>  6 audi             6        234
#>  7 audi             7        234
#>  8 audi             8        234
#>  9 audi             9        234
#> 10 audi            10        234
#> # ... with 224 more rows
#> 
#> Grouped by:  manufacturer  [15 | 16 (11)]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

My attempt is unsuccessful because column `n_in_group` gives the total number of rows in `mpg`, rather than the size of each group.

How can I utilize `collapse` tools to achieve the same output as in my `dplyr`-based code shown at the beginning?

Comment: I did not know `collapse`, it's a great package! Does this work for you: `mpg |> fgroup_by(manufacturer) |> GRP()`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, thanks. Your suggestion is in the right direction. However, it requires quite some wrangling to end up with the data format I need.  Please note that had we done `mpg %>% fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>% ftransform(idx = seq_row(.)) %>% fsummarise(n_in_group = fNobs(idx))` we would have gotten pretty closer. Yet, I'm sure there's a more straightforward way to get the desired output directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent method is:

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)

mpg %>%
  fselect(manufacturer) %>%
  ftransform(more_than_10_obs = fnobs(manufacturer, manufacturer, TRA = "replace") > 10)

# A tibble: 234 x 2
   manufacturer more_than_10_obs
 * <chr>        <lgl>           
 1 audi         TRUE            
 2 audi         TRUE            
 3 audi         TRUE            
 4 audi         TRUE            
 5 audi         TRUE            
 6 audi         TRUE            
 7 audi         TRUE            
 8 audi         TRUE            
 9 audi         TRUE            
10 audi         TRUE            
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Check that it gives the same result as `dplyr`:

```
collapse_res <- mpg %>%
  fselect(manufacturer) %>%
  ftransform(more_than_10_obs = fnobs(manufacturer, manufacturer, TRA = "replace") > 10)

dplyr_res <- mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  mutate(more_than_10_obs  = n() > 10) %>%
  ungroup()

identical(dplyr_res, collapse_res)

[1] TRUE
```

Edit:

To group by multiple variables, simply pass them as a list:

```
mpg %>%
  fselect(manufacturer, class) %>%
  ftransform(more_than_10_obs = fnobs(manufacturer, list(manufacturer, class), TRA = "replace") > 10)
```

Comment: This answer is great, thank you! I now realize that I made a problematic assumption. In my real data I group by more than one variable. Now I don't know how to adapt your solution to a situation where group by several variables. If not too much of a trouble, could you please supplement your answer with how you'd use `fnobs()` to get an output equivalent to `mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, class) %>% mutate(more_than_10_obs = n() > 10)`?

Comment: Also, if I may ask -- the `x` argument in `fnobs()` is currently set to `manufacturer`. Does it actually matter which column we choose to specify as `x`?

Comment: Not if `x` contains no missing values.