# How to count the amount of records for a variable

Tags: r

I would like to learn how to count the amount of records associated with a variable.
I have a real big dataset which has 2 types of users (casual & member), I want to know the total amount of rides a type of user asked for the service.

dataset

[image: 1]

Comment: Include data as a text and not image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with the iris dataset and data.table package.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)
DT[, .(count = .N), by = Species]
```

https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/index.html