# How to find instances per county when given all instances

Tags: r, geography

I have a data table containing crashes, with county as an attribute for each. I would like to count the number of instances per county and add this number to a data table containing one row per county.

So far I haven't been able to find any documentation for this. I need to generalize it such that every county gets tallied up. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `aggregate` by county and gather the sum of instances from the multiple county lines. There are many worked examples on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)