# Obtaining Counts of Columns Values based on Unique Combinations of Multiple other Column Values

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset and I need a count, for each email address, of how often each email address appears on different dates and across conditions (condition 1 v 2). From the following dummy data, I would like a table that shows, for each unique name, a count for the number of times that name appears with each unique combination of condition and date, using R.

```
set.seed(1)
start_date <- as.Date('2015-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2015-01-05')   
date_vec=as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), 30, 
                    replace = T), origin = '1970-01-01')

people=c("Sam","Jim","Sally","Robert","Donnie")
Condition=sample(1:2,30, replace = "TRUE")
dates=sample(1:6,20, replace = "TRUE")
people_column=sample(people,30, replace = "TRUE")
sample_df=data.frame(people_column,Condition,date_vec)
```

Comment: `count(sample_df, people_column, Condition, date_vec)` or `table(sample_df)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)

Comment: RE the table function, this just about works, but, is there any way that I can specify the order of the separation. If I just do it as is, then it separates a different table by date, and then each name next to a column of counts for condition. Is there a way to reverse this?

RE the count command, this almost works.

Is there a way to make it so there would be a table that might have conditions 1 and 2 as columns and then dates as sub columns as one might do on an excel pivot table. I realize that there is a pivot_wider function in dplyr but I have not been able to get it to do this..

Comment: It might be more helpful if you include a desired output table, to illustrate. I don't actually know what you mean by "conditions 1 and 2 as columns and then dates as sub columns as one might do on an excel pivot table"