# Add count of unique / distinct values by group to the original data

Tags: r, count, unique, aggregate

I wish to count the number of unique values by grouping of a second variable, and then add the count to the existing data.frame as a new column. For example, if the existing data frame looks like this:

```
  color  type
1 black chair
2 black chair
3 black  sofa
4 green  sofa
5 green  sofa
6   red  sofa
7   red plate
8  blue  sofa
9  blue plate
10 blue chair
```

I want to add for each `color`, the count of unique `types` that are present in the data:

```
  color  type unique_types
1 black chair            2
2 black chair            2
3 black  sofa            2
4 green  sofa            1
5 green  sofa            1
6   red  sofa            2
7   red plate            2
8  blue  sofa            3
9  blue plate            3
10 blue chair            3
```

I was hoping to use `ave`, but can't seem to find a straightforward method that doesn't require many lines. I have >100,000 rows, so am also not sure how important efficiency is.

It's somewhat similar to this issue: [Count number of observations/rows per group and add result to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450600/how-do-i-count-aggregate-values-from-a-data-frame-and-reincorporate-them-into-th)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Using `ave` (since you ask for it specifically):

```
within(df, { count <- ave(type, color, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))})
```

Make sure that `type` is character vector and not factor.

---

Since you also say your data is huge and that speed/performance may therefore be a factor, I'd suggest a `data.table` solution as well.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, count := uniqueN(type), by = color] # v1.9.6+
# if you don't want df to be modified by reference
ans = as.data.table(df)[, count := uniqueN(type), by = color]
```

`uniqueN` was implemented in `v1.9.6` and is a faster equivalent of `length(unique(.))`. In addition it also works with data.frames/data.tables.

---

Other solutions:

Using plyr:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(color), mutate, count = length(unique(type)))
```

Using `aggregate`:

```
agg <- aggregate(data=df, type ~ color, function(x) length(unique(x)))
merge(df, agg, by="color", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: using `length(unique(type))` in the `plyr` version is only equivalent to `data.table::uniqueN(type)` if you have no NA values. `uniqueN` will report 0 for empty groups whereas `length(unique(type))` will report 1! The `dplyr` (not sure about `plyr`) equivalen of `data.table::uniqueN(x, na.rm = TRUE)` is `dplyr::n_distinct(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 88):

Here's a solution with the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package - it has `n_distinct()` as a wrapper for `length(unique())`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  mutate(unique_types = n_distinct(type))
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr solution Sam. Let's say I wanted to go one step further and "subset" df to include only "color" and the "corresponding number of distinct types". I remember there is a slick function for these but I can't remember, advice?

Answer (score 9):

This can be also achieved in a vectorized without by group operations by combining `unique` with `table` or `tabulate`

If `df$color` is `factor`, then

Either

```
table(unique(df)$color)[as.character(df$color)]
# black black black green green   red   red  blue  blue  blue 
#    2     2     2     1     1     2     2     3     3     3
```

Or

```
tabulate(unique(df)$color)[as.integer(df$color)]
# [1] 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

If `df$color` is `character` then just

```
table(unique(df)$color)[df$color]
```

---

If `df$color` is an `integer` then just

```
tabulate(unique(df)$color)[df$color]
```