# Removing rows from a dataframe based on a conditional statement?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (call it `df`) of accidents. Each accident has a # associated with it, a # for each person involved, and the type of accident. It looks something like this:

```
x               y                    z
accident #1   person A    accident type #1
accident #1   person A    accident type #2
accident #2   person A    accident type #1
accident #2   person B    accident type #2
accident #2   person B    accident type #3
accident #3   person C    accident type #1
```

In the above case, person A was involved in two accidents. In the first accident, there were two 'types' of accidents that person A was involved with. Person B was involved with person A, but was only involved in one accident, with two accident types. Person C was also involved in only one accident.

I want to collect **the subset of people who have only been involved in one accident**. However, I want to include all of their accident types. So using the above example, I would want this:

```
x               y                    z
accident #2   person #2    accident type #2
accident #2   person #2    accident type #3
accident #3   person #3    accident type #1
```

How might I do this in R?

Comment: Indent four spaces to make code blocks, or highlight and press CTRL+K

Comment: please google this, as it's quite a common operation

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm new to R and am unsure what exactly to Google. Nothing I've found matches my specific case.

Comment: Then explicate what you've found, and why it doesn't apply -- demonstrating effort goes a long way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421776/how-to-add-count-of-unique-values-by-group-to-r-data-frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [dplyr package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), using `group_by`, `filter`, and `n_distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(x) == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setcolorder(setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(x)==1] , y], names(df))[]
#            x        y                z
#1: accident #2 person B accident type #2
#2: accident #2 person B accident type #3
#3: accident #3 person C accident type #1
```