# Subsetting for a minimum number of locations for MCP in R, dropping individual names

Tags: subset, records, adehabitathr

I have a very similar question to that posted here: [Subsetting for a minimum number of locations for MCP in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183087/subsetting-for-a-minimum-number-of-locations-for-mcp-in-r/47947735#47947735)

And here [Subset data frame based on number of rows per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204257/subset-data-frame-based-on-number-of-rows-per-group/20204630#20204630)

Where I'm trying to subset a dataset dropping all individuals with less than 5 observations.

df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), x = 1:9)

In this case, retain only the records for individual 'a'

I manage to subset my dataset fine with any of the solutions posted in the links above, but it still retains all the individuals' names with 0 records

e.g. in my dataset, table(df$name)

shows 
a b 
6 0

Instead, I need to get rid of those individuals alltogether from the dataset. 
(otherwise I still get the error line " At least 5 relocations are required to fit an home range", because the names with less than 5 are still retained in there)

The trick that does it to run this line before: 
 df$name<-as.numeric(df$name) 
a 
6

But in this way I lose the labels for the individuals, which i need for the rest of my analyses.

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult for me to give an answer without your full code. However, the below code could solve your problem.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                 x = 1:9)
ss_df <-subset(df, df$name == "a")
ss_df$name <- factor(ss_df$name)
```

The keypoint is that you need to reset the factor level of your dataframe, for this, `factor`function is used.