# Subset data frame based on a column number threshold

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like that:

```
Bacteria                  feature_id s_counts   s1   s2      s3   s4    s5   s6
s__Bacillus_thuringiensis c34ed8     4745       0    1300    12    0    190  230   
s__Bacillus_pumilus       d73583     333        333  0       0     0    0    0
```

I would like to filter and retain only rows whose counts are >0 in at least 4 columns from column s1 to ncol, so I could get it:

```
Bacteria                  feature_id s_counts   s1   s2      s3   s4    s5   s6
s__Bacillus_thuringiensis c34ed8     4745       0    1300    12    0    190  230
```

This is similar to this question [Subset data frame based on number of rows per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204257/subset-data-frame-based-on-number-of-rows-per-group) unless that I am interested in the columns instead of rows, so I couldn't figure it out how to "adapt the solution" to cols. I can't see a way of grouping the data as I need the columns instead of the rows.
Could someone help me on that? Also, I would appreciate a solution with dplyr, if possible.

Cheers,

Leo

Comment: You need `rowSums`. Something like `df[rowSums(df[-c(1:2)] > 0) > 4,]`

Comment: That is throwing an error "Error in `[.default`(df, -1:2) : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts", but someone did post a working answer and then deleted

Comment: Try it again...I edited and It shouldn't throw it anymore. Also check out the target I duped it with

Comment: `>df
                   Bacteria feature_id s_counts  s1   s2 s3 s4  s5  s6
1 s__Bacillus_thuringiensis     c34ed8     4745   0 1300 12  0 190 230
2       s__Bacillus_pumilus     d73583      333 333    0  0  0   0   0
> df[rowSums(df[-1:2] > 0) <4,]
Error in `[.default`(df, -1:2) : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Comment: Check my comment again. Re-copy it, but most importantly, check out the dupe target

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working! I am going to check the other post you mentioned.