# How to drop the unbalanced groups from panel data in R

Tags: r, panel

I am working with the dataset HealthIns from the 'pglm' package in R. I would like to drop all the individuals that have a different from 5 number of observations (some of them are observed only for three years). Therefore I want to create a new dataframe only with the individuals for which I have the data for the years 1,2,3,4,5.
Any suggestion about how I can do it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried. This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204257/subset-data-frame-based-on-number-of-rows-per-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's find out which ids are having data for all five years:

```
# Load library
library(tidyverse) 

complete <- HealthIns %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(n == 5) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

Now we can use it to filter the data:

```
df <- HealthIns %>% 
  filter(id %in% complete)
```

Let's check if `df` is correct:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   year [5]
   year     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1  1584
2     2  1584
3     3  1584
4     4  1584
5     5  1584
```

As you can see `df` is having same amount of observations for each year value.