# Counting daily occurrences of an event over a year

Tags: r, count, data.table, xts, reshape2

I have the following data set over 6 months and I need to compute the number of individuals choosing options A, B or C on a daily basis (the options are several characters in length).

```
User    Date        Option     
90   2013-01-28       A      
26   2013-02-04       B      
23   2013-02-04       A     
23   2013-01-07       C      
84   2013-02-27       B     
57   2013-01-30       A
```

Ultimately, I'm hoping for the dataframe to have the following form.

```
   Date      Option     Count
2013-01-01     A         203
2013-01-01     B         75
2013-01-01     C         134
2013-01-02     A         214
```

I've tried several alternatives using reshape2, data.tables (using table or count as FUN) and xts but I have been unable to obtain the desired results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450600/count-number-of-observations-rows-per-group-and-add-result-to-data-frame

Comment: Thanks to both nrussell & Frank! I appologize for the duplication...I hadn't seen that thread!