# Add column with count of values (not a summary, neither a pivot)

Tags: r, dplyr

Toy data:

```
dat <- structure(list(
  country = c("USA", "USA", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan"),
  values = c(25, 30, 20, 45, 31)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I want to add a column 'N', which contains the number of observations per country.

Desired output:

```
#  country values  N
1     USA     25   2
2     USA     30   2
3   Japan     20   3
4   Japan     45   3
5   Japan     31   3
```

I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186133/faster-ways-to-calculate-frequencies-and-cast-from-long-to-wide) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072147/count-observations-of-distinct-values-per-group-and-add-a-new-column-of-counts-f). But I do not want to create a summary and/or pivot the data as in these questions.

I only want to add a column with the number of observations. I guess this is extremely easy, but I cannot make it work!

Please note, I need to use the pipe.

Comment: `dplyr::add_count(dat, country, name = "N")`

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below.

```
dat |> 
  mutate(N= n(), .by=country)
```

**output**

```
  country values N
1     USA     25 2
2     USA     30 2
3   Japan     20 3
4   Japan     45 3
5   Japan     31 3
```