# Resuming a Table using only DPLYR package

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the dplyr package, I trying to make a summary table from a data_table like this:

```
vector_one = c("name1", "name2", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name1")
vector_two = c("apple", "apple", "grape", "grape", "grape", "apple")
my_df = cbind(vector_one, vector_two)
```

| vector_one | vector_two |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | apple |
| name2 | apple |
| name1 | grape |
| name2 | grape |
| name2 | grape |
| name1 | apple |

and I want a resume like this, but using only base-R and DPLYR:

```
table_vec = cbind(c("name" = c(2,1)), c("name" = c(1,2)))
colnames(table_vec) = c("apple", "grape")
table_vec
```

|  | apple | grape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 2 | 1 |
| name2 | 1 | 2 |

But I not having any luck...

I tried using summarise, group_by, across, and a few other functions from dplyr. Any ideas?

Comment: In your example `class(my_df)` is matrix/array. In your real data are you using a matrix or are you using a data.frame (as the variable kind of implies).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072147/count-observations-of-distinct-values-per-group-and-add-a-new-column-of-counts-f (or a duplicate of one of those duplicates)

Comment: First of all this is not a duplicate!. The OP is asking for a dplyr only solution. There is no answer with a dplyr only solution to this question (in all referenced links). Therefore I opt to open the question. One possible solution is : `library(dplyr) #>1.1.0 my_df %>%
  summarise(
    apple = sum(if_else(vector_two == "apple", 1,0)),
    grape = sum(if_else(vector_two == "grape", 1,0)), .by = vector_one)
  )`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use base R‘s table function:

```
my_df <- data.frame(vector_one, vector_two)

table(my_df$vector_one, my_df$vector_two)

        apple grape
  name1     2     1
  name2     1     2
```

Comment: I didnt know this functions exists

Comment: Why do you need a `data.frame` ie you could easily do `table(vec_1, vec_2)` or if you have the dataframe, just do `table(my_df)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potential solution using only `dplyr`, although its applicability may depend on the specific requirements of the original poster (OP):

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr > 1.1.0

my_df %>%
  summarise(
    apple = sum(if_else(vector_two == "apple", 1,0)),
    grape = sum(if_else(vector_two == "grape", 1,0)), .by = vector_one)
  )

  vector_one apple grape
1      name1     2     1
2      name2     1     2
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote -- you could shorten this by summing the logical values directly (e.g. `sum(vector_two == "apple")`)

Comment: These assums you only have two values, while you can have as many values in each of the variable

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a formula in `xtabs`, but the default works here:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(data = my_df))

#       apple grape
# name1     2     1
# name2     1     2
```