# R count over group in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c("A","A","B"))
```

What's the simplest way of adding another column to this that has the count of each occurrence of the column group?

The result should look like the following:

```
  group count
1     A     2
2     A     2
3     B     1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450600/count-number-of-rows-per-group-and-add-result-to-original-data-frame

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(count = n())
```